# Node Webkit brings up 'document not defined' error

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, easeljs

I'm trying to run an easel.js based script using node webkit. The error I get though is 'document not defined'. The script in question does work in a normal browser attached to a html file I should add.

I have used window.document to attach a event listener for keyboard input and I think this is what's causing the problem(?)

Comment: Are you load your scripts in `index.html` or using `require`? You can try to make `global.document = window.document`. Because document suppose to be accessible directly. Can you give a piece of code in easel.js which causes error?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this. The problem was caused by not adding all the files I needed into the zip file (a very obvious mistake)